# Cannot use bundle id after automatic manage signing

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I accidentally checked "automatic manage signing" and I think it used up my bindle id. Screenshot below. Is it possible tofree this bundle id so I don't get error when creating it on the iOS creating app id website, screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMgRe.png

[image]

Comment: Thanks @matt I'm trying to find that and delete it so I can reuse it.

Comment: @matt I'm looking here but i don't see `org.reactjs.native.diddodum` :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems Xcode has created the AppID automatically for you. 
So open Xcode->Preferences window, and go to the "Accounts" tab. The AppID has been created from one of the accounts listed in there. So you should log in to the Apple Dev Center with each account in the list, go to AppIds section and check where it was created and delete it.
(You should look for the "**XC org reactjs native diddodum**")

And I think you should start with the account to whom belongs the team that is shown in "Build Settings" tab under "Development Team" section.

---

I haven't seen your screenshot, so obviously, that team is "Noitidart Molyneux".

---

If in the Accounts tab you see only one account, that means that you don't need no manually create an AppId, it already exists in your account. So just go to AppIds section, find that AppId, and edit it in your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out and then accept answer. The thing is though, that Noitidart Molyneux has no account associated with it. I don't use this for production, just local testing.

Comment: I'm looking https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle but i don't see `org.reactjs.native.diddodum` :(